# POSTFIX: header_checks redirect to several mails

Tags: postfix, regex

I have a regex rule like this:

```
/^Subject: *SOME TEXT*/ REDIRECT email1@some.com, email2@some.com
```

And the receiving server interprets that as a single mail, not two and understandably throws email format errors.

How can i reformat the destinations so POSTFIX read them as two or more and resends to each separate mail (if possible)?

Thanks

EDIT:

Also tried with duplicated rules like:

```
/^Subject: *SOME TEXT*/ REDIRECT email1@some.com
/^Subject: *SOME TEXT*/ REDIRECT email2@some.com
```

And only works the first one, not the second.

Comment: One method could be to create a local alias group and put all the addresses in it.  Another would be to create a distribution list on the receiving end, if they are on the same domain / mail server.

Comment: I tried that but I'm getting some domain issues that's why i wanted to dig a little more into this alternative.